# Sorting a 2D array using the second column C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have to sort a 2D array of ranks and names (used as strings) based on the second column. I'm trying to sort it in alphabetical order but I can't seem to get it right. I'm still new to multi-dimensional arrays, so I'm still quite confused. I'm using `Bubble Sort`, and it is sorting the names, but not in the right order.

this is the array I'm trying to sort:

```
const int ROWS=6;
const int COLS=2;

string names [ROWS][COLS] = { "1", "Jacob",
                              "2", "Michael",
                              "3", "Joshua",
                              "4", "Matthew",
                              "5", "Ethan",
                              "6", "Andrew"};
```

this is what I get:

```
2 Michael
4 Matthew
3 Joshua
1 Jacob
6 Andrew
5 Ethan
```

and this is the sort function I'm using:

```
void sort (string names [][COLS], int size)
{    
    int i,j; // i = rows 
    string hold1, hold2;

    for (i=0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (names [i][1] > names [j][1]) //names  = col 1 , rank = col 0
            {
                hold1 = names [i][1];
                hold2 = names [i][0];
                names [i][1] = names [j][1];
                names [i][0] = names [j][0];
                names [j][1] = hold1;
                names [j][0] = hold2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I finally got it to work. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're actually swapping the elements back and forth. You need to make sure that when you're Bubble Sorting you're only comparing an element with a *later* element. That is:

```
for (i=0; i < size-1; i++)
{
    for (j=i+1; j < size; j++)
          ^^^^
    {
        // same as before
    }
}
```

Note that we can take advantage of standard utilities to make this code a lot easier to understand. The line I wrote as `//same as before`... what you're doing there is just swapping `names[i]` and `names[j]`, which we can spell:

```
std::swap(names[i], names[j]);
```

That's just easier to understand and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You got the bubble sort wrong. try this :

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j < size-1; j++)
    {
        if (names [j][1] > names [j+1][1])
        {
            hold1 = names [j][1];
            hold2 = names [j][0];
            names [j][1] = names [j+1][1];
            names [j][0] = names [j+1][0];
            names [j+1][1] = hold1;
            names [j+1][0] = hold2;
        }
    }
}
```