# Python - Sorting a 2D array using each column

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort a 2D array with three columns in the following fashion:

- First, the array goes through the one of the columns and sorts each number based on the value.
- Then, if there are any "ties", the program uses another column to sort out the ties.
- Finally, it uses the remaining column to sort out any ties still existing.

Example:

```
[[6, 0, "Hello"],
 [4, 1, "Jane"],
 [3, 0, "Text"],
 [4, 1, "Bob"]]
```

The columns in order of importance are: 1, 0, 2. This means we check the 2nd column, then the first, and finally the last.

```
[[6, 0, "Hello"],
 [3, 0, "Text"],
 [4, 1, "Jane"],
 [4, 1, "Bob"]]
```

Now, we use the first column:

```
[[3, 0, "Text"],
 [6, 0, "Hello"],
 [4, 1, "Jane"],
 [4, 1, "Bob"]]
```

Finally, we use the last column:

```
[[3, 0, "Text"],
 [6, 0, "Hello"],
 [4, 1, "Bob"],
 [4, 1, "Jane"]]
```

It is not hard to just sort it based on one column and disregard any duplicates. That is shown here: [Sorting a 2D array using the second column C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712274/sorting-a-2d-array-using-the-second-column-c). I tried `data.sort(key=itemgetter(1))`, but it only worked for one column.

I have no idea how to proceed with this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [[6, 0, "Hello"],
        [4, 1, "Jane"],
        [3, 0, "Text"],
        [4, 1, "Bob"]]

data.sort(key=itemgetter(1, 0, 2))

print(data)  # [[3, 0, 'Text'], [6, 0, 'Hello'], [4, 1, 'Bob'], [4, 1, 'Jane']]
```

To help understand:

```
key_function = itemgetter(1, 0, 2)
print(key_function([6, 0, "Hello"]))  # (0, 6, 'Hello')
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried data.sort(key=itemgetter(1, 0, 2)) but I didn't know that it could take more than one parameter.